# How to change color of a point with my class CSS and Angular

Tags: angular

I Have a 3 folder : CSS , HTML and TypeScript.

I want my points to change color depending on the level. My colors are in the CSS.

Level 1: Yelow
Level 2: Green
Level 3: Blue
Level 4: Red

Comment: Your question seems to be unclear. What do you want to achieve can you explain bit more along with the code.

Comment: please show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Use ngClass like below

```
<ul *ngFor="let person of people">
  <li [ngClass]="{
    'text-success':person.country === 'UK',
    'text-primary':person.country === 'USA',
    'text-danger':person.country === 'HK'
  }">{{ person.name }} ({{ person.country }})
  </li>
</ul>
```

Refer https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/